# Xdebug for remote server not connecting

Tags: php, netbeans, xdebug

I want a team using different computers to be able to debug PHP on a **remote** server, but I am having a hard time getting Xdebug to work in NetBeans 7.0.1. I’ve tried many online tips, but to no avail.

For the record, I have successfully installed Xdebug **locally** on a Windows 7 machine running WampServer. So I *can* debug PHP with breakpoints in NetBeans, provided I set the *Project Properties->Run Configuration->Run As* property to *Local Web Site*. However, as stated above my goal is to debug in NetBeans on a *Remote Web Site*.

My server is a Ubuntu 11.04 machine. I have used the output from http://www.xdebug.org/find-binary.php to put the proper binary on the machine. I have modified all `php.ini` files I could find (in both the `php5/apache2` and `php5/cli` directories) to include these lines:

```
zend_extension="/usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/xdebug.so"
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9000
```

If I check the `phpinfo.php` web page, it says:

```
This program makes use of the Zend Scripting Language Engine:
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.1.2, Copyright (c) 2002-2011, by Derick Rethans
```

So Xdebug does seem to be installed properly. Still, when I try debugging in NetBeans, I get the endless status bar message *Waiting For Connection (netbeans-xdebug)*. When I hit the stop button I get *No connection from xdebug was detected within X seconds. The reason could be that xdebug is not installed or not properly configured*.

Maybe I'm confusing local settings with server settings here? [A post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4528569/xdebug-and-netbeans-problem) said `xdebug.remote_host` should be set to the *IP of the machine running NetBeans*, but I want a team to be able to debug using machines with different IP addresses. A problem could be port 9000, but I have checked that it is not blocked.

Any help that could clarify this would be appreciated!

Comment: Using ``xdebug.ide_key`` and setting it to some complex value should serve as a password, iirc.

Comment: Running into this problem again years later, the problem was caused by a firewall setting that prevented the server running Xdebug from contacting my development computer (see @Linus Kleen's answer). So check your firewall.

Comment: Yea, some kind of NA(P)T eventually is required to forward incoming external connection from development server to your computer in local area network.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

The server running PHP (and XDebug) needs to be able to connect to your workstation/desktop.

[image: Diagram]

So you'll need the server set up accordingly by either telling it to connect to a *specific* IP-address (`xdebug.remote_host`) or to automatically "connect back" (`xdebug.remote_connect_back`). The latter has some security implications, though. These are outlined [in the manual](http://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#remote_connect_back).

Comment: Many thanks! It now works! I simply added the configuration lines `xdebug.remote_connect_back=1` to the php.ini files. Also thanks for noting the security implications.

Comment: Checking the documentation, the `xdebug.remote_host` setting seems to accept only one address, and with many team members with different IP addresses it seems to me `xdebug.remote_connect_back=1` is the only setting that works.

Comment: You could set up multiple virtual hosts that have a dedicated `php.ini` to circumvent the connect-back issue. Our development department is set up like that.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds like a solution (albeit a quite cumbersome one). I hope Xdebug will be updated in the future to accept multiple hosts in the `xdebug.remote_port` setting.

Comment: Using ``xdebug.ide_key`` and setting it to some complex value should serve as a password, iirc.

Comment: @LinusKleen I have setup the remote_connect_back but Nginx start showing 504 gateway timeout error...please note I have tried increase timeout in nginx config too...any suggestion for me?

Comment: @user269867 Does [this question](http://serverfault.com/questions/178671/nginx-php-fpm-504-gateway-time-out-error-with-almost-zero-load-on-a-test-se) help?

Comment: Wouldn't you also need to either forward port 9000 from your router to your local development machine, or else use SSH tunneling to connect to the remote debug session?

Comment: @ButtleButkus You'd need to if the debugged machine and the PC doing the debugging are on separate networks; not so, if they're not.

Comment: @LinusKleen could you give any hint about SSH tunneling? I think I understand the basic concept, that the two machines can communicate as if they are on port 9000 but actually they are communicating through port 22. Yes? I followed this jetbrains tutorial (https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Remote+debugging+in+PhpStorm+via+SSH+tunnel) but Xdebug on the remote server still can't connect to my port 9000 (timeout). I can't tell if the tunnel is actually "working" - how would the remote server's Xdebug output know to go through the tunnel instead of directly to my blocked port 9000?

Comment: @ButtleButkus In short, if machine **A** needs to connect to **B** via port 9000, but that port is blocked, it establishes a common SSH session and instructs the SSH client (on machine **A**) to set up a port 9000 *locally*. Connections to this local port are then *tunneled* via SSH to target machine **B**. Not much room left here in the comment field; ask a question about this if you need more details.

Comment: @LinusKleen I hope this question is not too long and/or general. Let me know. Thank you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33424393/explain-ssh-tunneling-process-and-limitations-for-a-remote-xdebug-session

Comment: I am using PHP5.6 and XDebug2.5.5 How is the configuration for my case. Can you please look into https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70092201/netbeans-xdebug-remote-host-waiting-for-connection-for-infinite-time

Answer (score 25):

## Xdebug 3 upgrade guide for remote debugging

Summary of: https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide

### Required PHP configuration changes/additions:

- remove `xdebug.`(`remote_enable`|`default_enable`|`profiler_enable`|`auto_trace`|`coverage_enable`)
- add `xdebug.mode=debug` OR use `develop`|`coverage`|`gcstats`|`profile`
- add `xdebug.start_with_request=yes`
- `xdebug.remote_autostart` is replaced by `xdebug.mode=debug` with `xdebug.start_with_request=yes`
- `xdebug.remote_host` is replaced by `xdebug.client_host`
- `xdebug.remote_port` is replaced by `xdebug.client_port` OR use new default in IDE setting (more below)

#### Example new configuration

```
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.start_with_request=yes
xdebug.idekey=myKey
xdebug.client_host=x.y.z.a
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
```

Where

- `x.y.z.a` = your IDE host
- `myKey` = your configured key in the IDE

### Required IDE configuration changes/additions:

- set `remote_port` to `9003` (xdebug's new default port) OR set `xdebug.client_port` to `9000` in the configuration above to keep the old default

Comment: Very correct answer; Thanks... In my case I had Win 10 with Php7.3.13, 
 Netbeans 8.2 and IIS 10 (browsers are Chrome with netbeans extension & FF)... Then I installed xdebug(using wizard) and config as below:

Comment: Just want to add that with Xdebug 3 - we should use `xdebug.discover_client_host=1` instead of `xdebug.remote_connect_back`

Comment: @Brad, I am using PHP5.6 and XDebug2.5.5 How is the configuration for my case. Can you please look into https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70092201/netbeans-xdebug-remote-host-waiting-for-connection-for-infinite-time

Comment: Thank you, I had a mix of old and new ways from wamp initial setup before upgrading and using your config above minus the idkey, worked perfectly! 

Answer (score 24):

For me, `xdebug.remote_connect_back = On` does not work.
What I did was to set ssh port forwarding on my client machine.

xdebug config on the remote machine:

```
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.remote_handler = dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode = req
```

forward ports on the client machine:

```
ssh -g -N -lusername -R9000:127.0.0.1:9000 [remote.host.ip]
```

The shell access on the remote machine must be allowed.

Comment: I believe this is called SSH tunneling, not port forwarding, although it is kind of similar. I think "port forwarding" generally refers to a public-facing router configured to send traffic to certain machines inside its private network depending on what port the traffic is for. I used that for setting up a web server on my home machine. Traffic for port 80 (http) was automatically sent to that machine (instead of, say, my room mate's).

Comment: Excellent, this works, can you explain what is going on, because I had used before a similar ssh command to make a proxy to a server, but that solution didnt work.

Answer (score 20):

The key directive is this:

```
xdebug.remote_connect_back = On
```

This allows the web server to connect to whatever computer is asking for a debugging session. This way you don't have to hard-code an IP address and are able to share Xdebug. This directive was not present in earlier versions and is often omitted from tutorials and documentation.

You also need to verify that every client computer accepts incoming connections to port 9000 (`xdebug.remote_port`). This includes configuring the firewall and making sure the debugger client is up and running

Comment: Thanks. I have read much Xdebug documentation but somehow overlooked the `xdebug.remote_connect_back` setting. Since NetBeans itself produces a help message with proposed php.ini settings, I assumed it was a matter of finding the right values for these settings rather than adding another new settings line.

Comment: I had to turn off `xdebug.remote_connect_back`. With an SSH tunnel, the remote machine is apparently supposed to connect to its own port 9000 (hence `xdebug.remote_port=9000` and `xdebug.remote_host=localhost`). Therefore, you don't want it to try to connect to the remote ip e.g. 173.12.34.25:9000, but localhost:9000. Also, the remote_host and connect_back options don't make sense to use together.

Answer (score 8):

In my case, those commands helped me:

```
xdebug.remote_enable = On
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
```

Notice: the debugger will work even if GET/POST/COOKIE variable is not present because of 'xdebug.remote_autostart=1'

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue a couple of times while trying to configure docker and after scratching my head multiple times I realized this was the way to fix it. So I decided to put this here as an answer for my future self.

Most of the time the Dockerfile was adding this this statement to php.ini:

```
xdebug.remote_connect_back     = on
```

This would cause everything to seem okay but somehow no debug connections were actually caught by PHP storm. Replacing the line above with the following instantly fixes stuff for me.

```
xdebug.remote_connect_back     = 0
xdebug.remote_host             = host.docker.internal
```

Of course, after that you still need to run:
`$ docker-compose down`
`$ docker-compose build` and
`$ docker-compose up -d`

Note: on Linux `host.docker.internal` will not work. You can use `172.17.0.1` instead. (Note it is not 127.0.0.1, I always thought it was because I'm a bit dyslectic)

Comment: that `host.docker.internal` bit...I can kiss you right now.

Comment: That only works on Mac or Windows, but not Linux where it is mostly used... I can't believe this kind of things... this make me angry...

Comment: I tried what I thought was the ip for host.docker.internal (172.17.0.1) and it didn't work; the host name sure does though! thanks!

Comment: @matiaslauriti on linux this works for me: `xdebug.remote_host=172.17.0.1`

Comment: @JulesColle still a no, that is your assigned ip for that docker... If I have to share that with a team, they will have to input their on IP... that is a no-no...

Comment: Sure, just saying it's working for me. I develop on 2 separate PCs, both running on Ubuntu. So as long as your team is working with linux or WSL, I guess this approach should work.

Comment: I am not using any Docker or PHPStorm. Can you please help me here 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70092201/netbeans-xdebug-remote-host-waiting-for-connection-for-infinite-time

Answer (score 3):

You will need set:

```
xdebug.remote_host=192.168.1.104
```

`192.168.1.104` is the client's ip, where you working with the IDE

Comment: Thanks. However, I don't think this approach works when you have several IPs you want to be able to connect to the Xdebug remote server. See the comment above by Linus Kleen.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for `xdebug.remote_connect_back = On` on server side php.ini
Also I had to use [this plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xdebug-helper/eadndfjplgieldjbigjakmdgkmoaaaoc) for Chrome to be able to start debugging session in PhpStorm

Answer (score 3):

If you are using xdebug 3, you need to know that some variables are renamed. Read this: https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide

php.ini configuration wich worked for me:

```
[xdebug]
xdebug.mode=debug
zend_extension="C:/wamp64/bin/php/php7.4.26/ext/php_xdebug.dll"
xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM
xdebug.client_host= "localhost"
xdebug.client_port=9003
```

[PHPstorm settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MGkth.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

What page extension are you firing up to start debugging? I remember I went nuts and spent sleepless nights where all settings with XDebug are going great. The problem was I was not starting up with `.PHP` rather starting up with `.HTML`.

If you are then try starting up your debugging with `.PHP` file.

Comment: I have a .PHTML file as startup file. It is recognized by NetBeans as a PHP file, at least judging by its icon. I tried changing to .PHP, but it didn't work. Thanks for the tip though!

Answer (score 1):

Very correct answer by Brad for xdebug 3; Thanks... In my case I had Win 10 with Php7.3.13,
Netbeans 8.2 and IIS 10(eindia.com is one among many websites ) (browsers are Chrome with netbeans extension & FF)... and no Xampp, Wampp, Lampp... Then I installed xdebug(using wizard) and config as below:

```
[xDebug]
zend_extension = "C:\Program Files\PHP\v7.3\ext\php_xdebug-3.0.2-7.3-vc15-nts-x86_64.dll"
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.start_with_request=yes
xdebug.remote_autostart=on
xdebug.remote_enable=on
xdebug.remote_handler="dbgp"
xdebug.client_host="eindia.com"
;xdebug.remote_host=192.168.1.5
;xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
xdebug.client_port=9003
;xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.idekey="netbeans-xdebug"
```

and its working like charm.

Answer (score 0):

## When using Laravel Sail

If you're using Laravel Sail, you need to add the line below to your `.env` file.

```
# Enable XDEBUG (PHP Debugger)
SAIL_XDEBUG_MODE=debug
```

After adding this, restart sail using `vendor/bin/sail restart`.

Fore more information see [the Laravel Sail docs](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/sail#debugging-with-xdebug).