# enable xdebug on bluehost shared server

Tags: php, apache, xdebug, ini, bluehost

I want to setup phpunit on a demo site on a bluehost shared server. I want to check if the php codes work on the environment after I made modifications and added more components.
With this, I need to set up xdebug. The problem is that my account is not allowed to download and install xdebug, I got permission denied.

```
pecl install xdebug
```

Then I read upon an answer here [Xdebug for remote server not connecting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049776/xdebug-for-remote-server-not-connecting). What I did is upload the xdebug.so file from my local, copy the /etc/php.ini to the server's public_html directory, and edited the php.ini file and and added the line below to refer to the xdebug.so file on the server.

```
zend_extension=/home1/user/public_html/xdebug.so
```

But after what I did, the phpinfo state that the xdebug is not enabled. Bluehost does not require to restart the apache. So it will refresh itself as I understand it. And the phpinfo state that the loaded ini file is the one on my public_html directory now.
Is this possible to enable xdebug this way?
Are there other ways to install/enable on bluehost shared server?

Comment: I curious to know if you found a solution to this.

Comment: was not able to find solution to this, i have to really on manual test instead of the automated testing