# Cannot parse server name for external Xdebug connection

Tags: phpstorm, xdebug

I have a Docker container with xdebug in it, when I run the script I need to form the Docker container I receive from PhpStorm the following message:

```
Cannot parse server name for external Xdebug connection.
To fix it create environment variable PHP_IDE_CONFIG on the remote server.
Windows: set PHP_IDE_CONFIG="serverName=SomeName"
Linux / Mac OS X: export PHP_IDE_CONFIG="serverName=SomeName".
```

but I have already set those environment variables as you can see in the screenshot here:

[image]

[xdebug.log](https://gist.github.com/panosru/76181f67e10faec8f23aea611f3d0cdb)

Here is the xdebug section from my `phpinfo()`:
[image]
[image]

And these are my settings for PhpStorm:

[image]

[image]

Environment from `phpinfo()`:

[image]

PHP Variables from `phpinfo()`:

[image]
[image]
[image]

I also tried to `export` env variables with and without quotes but the result was the same...

With quotes:

```
XDEBUG_CONFIG="remote_host=192.168.1.110"
PHP_IDE_CONFIG="serverName=docker-server"
```

Without quotes:

```
XDEBUG_CONFIG=remote_host=192.168.1.110
PHP_IDE_CONFIG=serverName=docker-server
```

The result from `ifconfig en1 inet` command from my MacOS where I'm running Docker and PhpStorm

[image]

You can also check the following files in cases needed:

- [Dockerfile.development](https://gist.github.com/panosru/b9acf5cd98b73af50ce0f3012f2d187e)
- [docker-compose.yml](https://gist.github.com/panosru/a6d08a1a10b96c9f6f731feb34d5808c)
- [environment.development](https://gist.github.com/panosru/cbe5cea49b9e45c7435a8ad71c986036)
- [php.ini](https://gist.github.com/panosru/2f2134d8bb19977227cf93845d1f3ca2)

Any help will be much appreciated!

## Update:

Seems that if I add

```
environment:
  XDEBUG_CONFIG: "remote_host=192.168.1.110"
  PHP_IDE_CONFIG: "serverName=docker-server"
```

into my `php` service located inside docker-compose.yml it solves the issue but leaves me with a big question.

Since I have:

```
env_file:
  - ./etc/environment.yml
  - ./etc/environment.development.yml
```

and inside `./etc/environment.development.yml` I have:

```
XDEBUG_CONFIG="remote_host=192.168.1.110"
PHP_IDE_CONFIG="serverName=docker-server"
```

And since it is not ignored and I can see that those Env variables are set even before I add `environment` property into my `php` service, why xdebug is only triggered when I have set the `environment` property? It feels like duplication for me to have it in both places and I prefer to have it inside `./etc/environment.development.yml` rather than `docker-compose.yml`.

Comment: 1) Do you really have DBGp Proxy running on your computer? It's simply not needed especially for local Docker... You may have configured it .. but do you actually use it? have you actually installed it etc. Better not to touch it if you do not know how exactly it works. 2) What web server you are using? nginx I guess... If so -- try configuring the server name there 3) *"I also tried to export env variables with and without quotes but the result was the same.."* It has to be **with**.

Comment: 4) What the full `phpinfo()` output is? I'm after _SERVER / ENVIRONMENT parts only -- need to check if server name is visible there. 5) So far xdebug log says that it's connected to some IDE, most likely PhpStorm... so overall it's good .. just that part left.

Comment: What exactly do you mean if I really have DBGp proxy running? That is a setting inside PhpStorm and as far as I know, you need that in order to debug remote php servers. The reason I tried both with and without double quote is because of [that](https://github.com/laradock/laradock/issues/363) bug. I'm familiar with remote debugging and I do it many times, but I now testing docker and want to switch over docker completely and while remote debugging works for me everywhere is not working with my docker instance.

Comment: @LazyOne I updated my original post to include Environment and PHP Variables section. Everything seems to be fine to me. The thing is that xdebug is connected to PhpStorm, but PhpStorm complains that "Cannot parse server name for external Xdebug connection."

Comment: 1) *"What exactly do you mean if I really have DBGp proxy running? That is a setting inside PhpStorm and as far as I know, you need that in order to debug remote php servers."* This means that you do not know how it works and when it's needed. Do not use it as you do not need it. See this if you wish to know when you *may* use it: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Multi-user+debugging+in+PhpStorm+with+Xdebug+and+DBGp+proxy

Comment: 2) *"The reason I tried both with and without double quote is because of that bug."* OK... so that's some Docker specific thing or something. I was actually referring to the actual command that you execute in console (i.e. `export PHP_IDE_CONFIG="serverName=SomeName"`) -- here they are needed.

Comment: 3) *"...but PhpStorm complains that... "* Does it still complains about it? For me (based on your info so far) that setup looks OK -- the other output from `phpinfo()` confirms that PHP_IDE_CONFIG is setup and can be seen by PHP. Maybe show more of your confg from PhpStorm side, e.g. how the server entry is defined there. If I may suggest to check these -- you may find some useful info: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44032296/783119 & https://stackoverflow.com/q/46263043/783119

Comment: I updated my original question. Even though that the env variables where setup correctly, when I added env variables to docker-compose.yml then it worked. I'm still not sure why it worked there but anyhow, is working now. I leave that question unanswered though since I believe that having env variables in docker-compose.yml is a duplication.

Comment: @LazyOne In regards to DBGp proxy, you are indeed correct, if I recall correctly it was suggested somehwere in PhpStorm youtrack or documentation and I was doing it since then, but I now removed my configuration from DBGp Proxy section and it still works, so yeah.. my bad after all. I'm removing the DBGp Proxy part from my original question and adding the appropriate setting section from PHP > Debug

Comment: *"Even though that the env variables where setup correctly, when I added env variables to docker-compose.yml then it worked"* So when it does NOT work .. do you see them in _ENV / _SERVER section of `phpinfo()` output? If you do not see them there ... then PhpStorm will not see them as well...

Comment: All the screenshots and the info I posted is when is not working. So I see everything correctly when is not working...

Answer (score 30, accepted):

After some more digging,

I saw the following difference:

When I use `env_file` directive I had the following in my `environment.development` file:

```
XDEBUG_CONFIG="remote_host=192.168.1.110"
PHP_IDE_CONFIG="serverName=docker-server"
```

which resulted in:
[image]

Notice the double quotes around the value.

When I was removing `env_file` directive and put the following:

```
environment:
  XDEBUG_CONFIG: "remote_host=192.168.1.110"
  PHP_IDE_CONFIG: "serverName=docker-server"
```

Then I had this in `phpinfo()`:
[image]

So in the end what I did was, I removed `environment` directive and put back the `env_file` directive and inside `environment.development` file I removed the double quotes around the value, so now it looks like that:

```
XDEBUG_CONFIG=remote_host=192.168.1.110
PHP_IDE_CONFIG=serverName=docker-server
```

And now it works fine :)

I filled a [bug report](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-41941) in PhpStorm youtrack.

Comment: Just to complete this, you can set this env variable directly in PHPStorm in the config of the CLI Interperters. Just take care to remove the double quotes too.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this with up. For me just putting    ` environment:
      - PHP_IDE_CONFIG=serverName=docker-server` did the fix. you don't really need env_file, just remove the quotes.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue with double quotes but in docker-compose. First version was wrong, removing double quotes solved it:

```
    environment:
      - PHP_IDE_CONFIG="serverName=local"
      - PHP_IDE_CONFIG=serverName=local
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped me too!