# Setup Xdebug for Shopware docker failed

Tags: xdebug, shopware, shopware6

I try to setup [Xdebug](https://xdebug.org/) for [shopware-docker](https://github.com/shyim/shopware-docker/wiki/Project-specific-Configuration#enabling-xdebug) without success.

> `VHOST_[FOLDER_NAME_UPPER_CASE]_IMAGE=ghcr.io/shyim/shopware-docker/6/nginx:php74-xdebug`
>
> After replacing your Folder Name and running `swdc up` Xdebug should be activated.

**Which *folder name* should I place?**
Using `myname`, the same name as in `/var/www/html/myname`, return error on `swdc up myname`:

```
swdc up myname
[+] Running 2/0
 ⠿ Network shopware-docker_default    Created                                                                                                                                  0.0s
 ⠿ Container shopware-docker-mysql-1  Created                                                                                                                                  0.0s
[+] Running 1/1
 ⠿ Container shopware-docker-mysql-1  Started                                                                                                                                  0.3s
.database ready!
[+] Running 0/1
 ⠿ app_myname Error                                                                                                                                                       1.7s
Error response from daemon: manifest unknown
```

**EDIT #1**
With this setup `VHOST_MYNAME_IMAGE=ghcr.io/shyim/shopware-docker/6/nginx:php81-xdebug` (**versioned** Xdebug) the app started:

```
// $HOME/.config/swdc/env
...
VHOST_MYNAME_IMAGE=ghcr.io/shyim/shopware-docker/6/nginx:php81-xdebug
```

But set a debug breakpoint (e.g. in `index.php`), **nothing happens**

**EDIT #2**
As @Alex recommend, i place `xdebug_break()` inside my code and it works.
Stopping on the breakpoint the debugger log aswers with hints/warnings [like described in the manual](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/troubleshooting-php-debugging.html#no-mappings):

> ...
> Cannot find a local copy of the file on server /var/www/html/%my_path%
> Local path is //var/www/html/%my_path%
> ...

- click on `Click to set up path mapping` to open the modal
  [image]
- click inside modal select input `Use path mapping (...)`
  [image]
- input field `File path in project` **response with *`undefined`***
  [image]

But **i have already set up the mapping** like described in the manual, go to `File | Settings | PHP | Servers`:
[image]

**Why does not work my mapping?** Where failed my set up?

Comment: Try to set a breakpoint with inserting `xdebug_break()` into the code. If that works, you might have a Problem with your directory mapping. Are you using PHPStorm or another IDE?

Comment: @Alex, yes, with the `xdebug_break` it works and yes, i use PHPStorm. How do i map the directory? Under `File -> Settings -> PHP -> Servers`? Could i map any provided files?

Comment: Yes, you just need to map the root directory there

Comment: @Alex see my **EDIT #2**

Comment: Sometimes there are problems with detecting the server name from the docker container. You might try something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50176116/288568

So what you are setting in the last screenshot seems correct, but PHPStorm/Xdebug might not apply it because the server name does not match.

Comment: But what if you supply the local path in the 2nd/3rd screenshot?

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue? I have the very same problem and I don't know how to get rid of it

Comment: @RobinSchambach I use xdebug_break() to debug

Answer (score 1):

The path mapping needs to be between your local project path on your workstation and the path inside the docker containers. Without xDebug has a hard time mapping the breakpoints from PHPStorm to the actual code inside the container.

If mapping the path correctly does not work and if its a possibility for you, i can highly recommend switching to http://devenv.sh for your development enviroment. Shopware itself promotes this new enviroment in their documentation: https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/installation/devenv and provides an example on how to enable xdebug:

```
# devenv.local.nix File
{ pkgs, config, lib, ... }:

{
  languages.php.package = pkgs.php.buildEnv {
    extensions = { all, enabled }: with all; enabled ++ [ amqp redis blackfire grpc xdebug ];
    extraConfig = ''
      # Copy the config from devenv.nix and append the XDebug config
      # [...]
      xdebug.mode=debug
      xdebug.discover_client_host=1
      xdebug.client_host=127.0.0.1
    '';
  };
}
```

A correct path mapping should not be needed here, as your local file location is the same for XDebug and your PHPStorm.