# NetBeans Xdebug Remote Host waiting for connection for infinite time

Tags: php, nginx, netbeans, xdebug, php-5.6

I am trying to configure Xdebug to my NetBeans IDE which is showing as "Waiting for Connection". I have already spent two days but I didn't find a clue on it.

- I am connecting to the code which is in the remote server from my NetBeans IDE using SFTP Connection which is successful.
- My Remote Server is a VM with the Cent OS 7.
- My Application is configured with nginx, PHP-FPM, PHP 5.6.

I have installed xdebug-2.5.5 in the server and added the following in the php.ini:

```ini
zend_extension=/apps/php-fpm/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_autostart=0
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler="dbgp"
xdebug.remote_mode="req"
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.idekey="netbeans-xdebug"
;xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger=0
xdebug.remote_log="/mypath/xdebug.log"
```

I have cross checked that `xdebug.so` is located in the correct path which I mentioned above.

In my NetBeans, Tools >> Options >> PHP >> Debugging:

```
Debugging port:  9000
Session ID: netbeans-xdebug
```

When I start the Debugging in NetBeans IDE, I am seeing the below logs:

```
Log opened at 2021-11-24 07:11:45
I: Connecting to configured address/port: localhost:9000.
I: Connected to client. :-)
-> <init xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" fileuri="file:///myserver/location/path/index.php" language="PHP" xdebug:language_version="5.6.14" protocol_version="1.0" appid="4643" idekey="netbeans-xdebug"><engine version="2.5.5"><![CDATA[Xdebug]]></engine><author><![CDATA[Derick Rethans]]></author><url><![CDATA[http://xdebug.org]]></url><copyright><![CDATA[Copyright (c) 2002-2017 by Derick Rethans]]></copyright></init>
    
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" status="break" reason="ok"><xdebug:message filename="file:///myserver/location/path/index.php" lineno="13"></xdebug:message></response>
    
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" status="stopping" reason="ok"></response>
    
Log closed at 2021-11-24 07:11:45
```

and in NetBeans IDE, "Waiting for Connection" is keep on loading for infinite time.

I am looking for some help to understand what is the problem on this. I am not using any Docker and PhpStorm. Looking forward for some help.

Comment: Hi @LazyOne, Can you please help me in fixing this problem?

Comment: You're using PHP 5.6 and Xdebug 2, neither of which is any more supported.

Answer (score 1):

You say "My Remote Server is a VM with the Cent OS 7" but then you have `xdebug.remote_host=localhost`

Xdebug is the one that connects to the IDE and NOT other way around. If your code is run on another server (another physical machine or inside the VM or some container) then `xdebug.remote_host` **should point to the machine where your IDE is running** (an IP address or domain name that can be resolved to that IP; as seen from that server). *Unless, of course, you are using reverse SSH tunnel for Xdebug connections.*

Right now you are connecting to some service on your server on TCP 9000 port. Extremely likely that it will be **php-fpm** (that also uses that port: that's one of the reasons why Xdebug v3 have changed the default port to be 9003 BTW). Your Xdebug log is a very short one: a typical response of a service that knows how Xdebug works that just closes the session. php-fpm can do just that.

So a few suggestions:

- To ensure that only Xdebug is using this port: change Xdebug port to another number (e.g. `9001` or maybe better `9003` so it will be compatible with Xdebug v3) in both php.ini as well as NetBeans. Do not forget to restart your web server/php-fpm after that (check live settings using `phpinfo();`).
- If no reverse SSH tunnel is used then set `xdebug.remote_host` to have an IP of the machine with your NetBeans. Quite often that would be the same IP as seen in `$_SERVER['REMOTE_HOST']`.

  NOTE: Since this will be an incoming connection the firewall on your local OS, on your server and your router (if it's outside of your LAN) can prevent such connection. So you would need to ensure that you can receive incoming connections on Xdebug port on your local machine.