# Must I use port 9000 for XDebug?

Tags: netbeans, wamp, xdebug

I am using:

- WAMP
- PHP 5.3
- XDebug
- NetBeans

I want to debug and have the debug port in Netbeans set as 9000 (after following various tutorials, including this one --> [Xdebug And Netbeans Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4528569/xdebug-and-netbeans-problem) ). The problem is, I'm unsure as to the purpose of the port 9000.

Does debug port 9000 mean that I must run Wamp on port 9000?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't run Wamp on port 9000: it's *NetBeans* that runs on port 9000!

Your debug client (NetBeans, in this case) needs to listen for incoming connections so Xdebug is able to establish a connection and send the apporpriate info. Please note that there're two requests involved:

1. Someone (possibly NetBeans) connects to the web server to request the HTML document and start a debug session.
2. Xdebug connects to whoever requested the debug session (NetBeans) and sends some XML with variables and other debug info.

Details can vary depending on your settings but this is the general idea.

The port you choose is irrelevant as far as:

- It's available (no other app is using it) at this moment.
- It's reachable from the web server (no firewall / router issues).

Comment: Hope you don't mind, I've tweaked the wording of the first sentence since it might have been confusing.